# Making Access database field structure changes propagate through to a Delphi app

Tags: ms-access, delphi, delphi-2007, ms-access-2000

I have a Delphi 2007 app that interacts with an Access 2000 database.  I have made changes to the database structure (addition of fields) and need to make them visible in the Delphi application but that is proving difficult.  I made a minimal Delphi application and Access database and the same issue is seen there.

My steps were:

- create an Access database with Field 1 and Field2
- use Settings/Control Panel/Administrative Tools/Data Sources (ODBC 32-bit) to create an alias to the MS database.
- create a Delphi application.
- add a `TDBGrid` to the form
- add a `TDataSource` onto the form
- set the `Datasource` property of the grid to `DataSource1`
- add a `TTable` to the form
- set the `Dataset` property of the `TDataSource` to `Table1`
- set the `DataBaseName` property of `Table1` to the alias name created for the database.
- set the `TableName` property to the name of the table in your original Access database.
- set the `Active` property of the Table to TRUE.  All the fields originally defined in the database appear in the grid.
  The problem is when I want to add fields later to this.  I can make them appear as columns in the grid by rebuilding the whole thing from scratch, but there must be an easier way!

What is accepted best practice for forcing database structure changes through to the Delphi IDE and resulting application?

** Answer to Ken White's comment **

Thanks Ken.  I appreciate the reasons for the `Columns` property of the `DBGrid` when you may not want all the fields in your grid - my issue is that when I use MS Access to add some fields to the table and then re-open my Delphi project:

- if I disconnect the `TTable` and reconnect it, the `FieldDefs` property shows the added fields. All good.
- I then move to the TDBGrid. The displayed columns don't show the additional fields, only the original ones. The `Columns` collection is empty.
- when I inspect the `Columns` property and try to add all fields I just get the original fields.  If I try to add one field` column, the picklist only gives me the original fields to choose from.

I don't understand why the `TTable` can see the new fields but the `TDatasource` (which has the TTable specified as it's `Dataset` property value) cannot.

Comment: The way to minimize problems when you change the structure of the db is to avoid using persistent TFields iin the datasets in the Delphi app and, if the Delphi dataset type is one which supports persistent TFieldDefs, avoid using those too.  There is nothing that these two types of pesistent collections can do that cannot be done in code instead, and you can make the code adaptable to changes in underlying dataset structure.  But there is no way of forcing changes through as you seem to envisage.

Comment: The reason this can't automatically be done is that the IDE has no way of knowing whether you want the new columns included or not. It's common, for instance, to create persistent fields to use in a TDBGrid to display to a user but not include every column in the table to that grid for display, or when you're using a related database from another application that includes columns you'll never use in your app.

Comment: Hi Ken, comments in question.